# How to convert "#00E4FF" to Brush in code?

Tags: silverlight

I need to convert some color ( in Hex ) to Brush. 
I need to do it in the code.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
//this would be initialized somewhere else, I assume
string hex = "#00E4FF";

//strip out any # if they exist
hex = hex.Replace("#", string.Empty);

byte r = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(0, 2), 16));
byte g = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(2, 2), 16));
byte b = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(4, 2), 16));

SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
```

Comment: Based on how MSDN defines the color structure, a valid color is also #FFF as well as #FFFF as well as #FFFFFF as well as #00FFFFFF. In either case you are betting that the hex string is six characters.

Comment: Well, that's what the question asked for. Should I have written an example for every possible color permutation, or can we all just agree to allow the question author a little freedom to use that grey matter?

Comment: Technically you are absolutely right. The gray matter should... be used appropriately. It is my opinion, however, that it's our responsibility as developers to write robust, scalable code; we should strive to write loosely coupled modules/code that can do the job in a manner that allows for maintainability and re-usability.

Comment: I totally agree. Which is why OP should write robust, scalable code. This is simply a technical answer, not a robust scalable solution. OP was stuck wanting to know a concept, so these answers helped him. Obviously we could scour StackOverflow and find instances where we can improve code examples and make them more reusable, but it's a bit presumptuous that I should build some module without knowing anything about what OP wants. Simple is often most effective in this context, or else the solution is lost amidst the noise.

Answer (score 11):

### Enhanced version (includes all colour formats);

I needed one of these that also works with the 3 digit "Shorthand hexadecimal form" and the MS alpha channel versions (for **Silverlight/WPF**), so came up with this version to cover all *numeric* colour formats:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert a Hex color string to a Color object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="htmlColor">Color string in #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb or #aarrggbb format</param>
/// <returns>A color object</returns>
public static Color ColorFromString(string htmlColor)
{
    htmlColor = htmlColor.Replace("#", "");
    byte a = 0xff, r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    switch (htmlColor.Length)
    {
        case 3:
            r = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(0, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            g = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(1, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            b = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(2, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            break;
        case 4:
            a = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(0, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            r = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(1, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            g = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(2, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            b = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(3, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            break;
        case 6:
            r = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            g = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            b = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            break;
        case 8:
            a = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            r = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            g = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            b = byte.Parse(htmlColor.Substring(6, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            break;
    }
    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

For a brush you use it like this:

```
return new SolidColorBrush(ColorFromString(colorString));
```

*Using byte.Parse is more efficient than Convert and requires no casting.*

Update: 
Fixed sub-string offsets for case 8.

Comment: Thank you for accounting of all variations of the color structure. This is probably how the internal color converter works as well. From what've seen this is the most complete answer so far.

Comment: @Meirion Hughes: Thanks for the correction. Cut/paste causes 99% of my bugs nowadays :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(7, 2), 16)
        )
    );
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks copied from http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/04/22/silverlight-get-color-from-hex.aspx and it throws an exception if used with the value provided in the question.

Comment: Same comment as before. Betting on an 8 character string, when the color code can be less than that, all the way down to 3.